# Can Wordpress plug-ins be applied to blogger?

Tags: wordpress, web, blogger

I've found suitable wordpress plug-in for my project, but I want to embed or use that plug-ins on blogger. Is it possible to use wordpress plug-in on blogger ? If yes, How to apply it ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use WordPress plug-ins with blogger. They are two different platforms. However, you can migrate from Blogger to WordPress with the built-in import function.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use WordPress plugins in blogger platform.